# Define many macros for rpmbuild at once?

Tags: scripting, rpm, rpmbuild

I would like to pass many macros into `rpmuild` without having to type out each macro manually, or even have a long makefile with `-D 'foo bar' -D 'foo bar' -D 'foo bar'` many times. I want to pass these macros into rpmbuild "all at once".

Let me describe my use case - I have a script called `buildid` that reports information about a build;

```
user@host: buildid -k tag
1.8.0-1444293343

user@host: buildid -k buildhost.platform
Linux-4.0.7-300.fc22.x86_64-x86_64-with-fedora-22-Twenty_Two

user@host: buildid -k version.formatted.gnu
1.8.0
```

I use these values in a RPM .spec file like this;

```
rpmbuild -ba foo.spec -D "tag `buildid -k tag`" -D "buildhost_platform `buildid -k buildhost.platform`" -D "version `buildid -k version.formatted.gnu`"
```

This is the sucky part - a long command line, with lots of typing. Even if I use a Makefile, it's still ugly.

My buildid script is pretty flexible though, and can save these buildid values to a file (.buildid_rpmmacros) or whatever, but better, can just print them out in a nice format like this;

```
user@host: buildid -f rpmmacros
%buildhost.hostname myhost.example.com
%buildhost.platform Linux-4.0.7-300.fc22.x86_64-x86_64-with-fedora-22-Twenty_Two
%buildhost.release 4.0.7-300.fc22.x86_64
%buildhost.system Linux
%buildhost.version #1 SMP Mon Jun 29 22:15:06 UTC 2015
%git.branch master
%git.revision 48a30d610cf1ab57dcc6947b2366b6a5e9a1fcc6
%git.revision.short 48a30d6
%tag 1.8.0-1444293343
%timestamp 1444293343
%version.formatted.gnu 1.8.0
%version.formatted.short 1.8.0
%version.formatted.win 1.8.0.0
%version.major 1
%version.minor 8
%version.release 
%version.revision 0
```

If I could do something like this, it would be ideal;

```
rpmbuild -ba foo.spec --macros-stdin < `buildid -f rpmmacros`
```

Finally, the macros are project/RPM specific, not global. This means storing them in `~/.rpmmacros` would not be a viable solution. I can save to a file easily (`buildid -nF rpmmacros`), but I'm already persisting them to a file in `ini` format, and just want to output them temporarily in RPM macro format (`buildid -f rpmmacro`)

---

Shameless plug - if you're interested in the `buildid` tool; https://github.com/jamesread/buildid

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to have reproducible builds you should use 'mock' rather than directly calling rpmbuild.
2. Mock can have configs and you put those macros to those config. E.g:

   ```
   $ cp /etc/mock/fedora-22-x86_64.cfg ~/my-project-fedora-22-x86_64.cfg
   $ vi ~/my-project-fedora-22-x86_64.cfg
   ```

put there this line:

```
config_opts['macros']['%Add_your_macro_name_here'] = "add macro value here"
```

And now you can build it with those macros defined:

```
$ mock -r ~/my-project-fedora-22-x86_64.cfg foo.src.rpm
```